# How to embed javascript code in a page using Powershell?

Tags: 2013, javascript, powershell

I have a powershell script that creates article pages in a publishing portal site collection. As part of that script I insert the content for each page by setting the value of the `$item["Page Content"]` field for the SPListItem that represents that page.

However, I must now insert a javascript block to that page as well. Suppose I have this block:
`<script type="text/javascript">alert('test');</script>`. If I add it to the `Page Content` field and call `Update()` it is not actually added to the rendered page's source code.

I understand that the correct way to do this via the Sharepoint UI is to use the `Embed Code` ribbon button. How can I do this with Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you use `Embed Code` is that a `Script Editor` web part is inserted into your page.

If you want to do that programmatically then read [Programmatically adding Web Parts to Rich Content in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-adding-web-parts-rich-content-sharepoint-2010/) down in the comment there is a powershell version of the code.

The web part has the following xml if exported:

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ScriptEditorWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Navigate</property>
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Allows authors to insert HTML snippets or scripts.</property>
        <property name="Content" type="string">&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;</property>
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Title" type="string">Script Editor</property>
        <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
        <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Width" type="unit" />
        <property name="Height" type="unit" />
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
        <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

If it's the same JavaScrip you want on all pages, then you might want to consider creating a Feature With a `<Control>` element to put it into `AdditionalPageHead`